# Arrow functions with void return type are not being type-checked?

Tags: typescript

Why does a `() => void` variable not enforce the return type of its assigned function?

```
// Error as expected
let x: void = 1

// No error?
let y: () => void = () => 1

// Error as expected
function z(): void { return 1 }
```

It seems weird that arrow functions behave differently than the other examples above.

The `() => undefined` type does what I would expect `() => void` to do.

```
// Error as expected
let foo: () => undefined = () => 1
```

I wonder if this is a bug?

Answer (score 2):

I found [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4544#issuecomment-145615015) that explains the rationale.

The idea is that `void` means the return type will be ignored. Thus, any return value is acceptable. In fact, the `void` type is a subtype of `any`.

It seems odd that named functions don't have the same behavior, though.

Comment: I think it's related to implicit vs. explicit `return`. Arrow functions without block scope implicitly return a value while TypeScript appropriately errors whenever a normal function explicitly returns when it's flagged not to.

Answer (score 2):

The semantics of the two are a bit different.

```
let y: () => void = () => 1
```

Here you define a variable `y` with a type annotation of `()=> void` which has a function assigned to it. The type of the assigned function is `() => number` based on the definition of the arrow function ( `()=> 1`). The two function types are compatible since when `y` is used the result should be ignored (since it is `void`) and the returned value from the implementation is ignored. The point is that typescript sees the arrow function and the type of `y` as two different things that are each typed independently and then checked for compatibility. While here the type annotation and the function definition are next to one another, they could be separate:

```
let x = () => 1   
let y: () => void = x
```

Also note that this is not only related to arrow functions, a regular function expression will have the same behavior:

```
let y: () => void = function() { return 1 } //ok
```

In the second case you are stating the return type of the function you are currently declaring should be `void`. Returning anything from such a function declaration is probably an error and flagged as such.